# Cardinality/Set Theory

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

For $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a<b$, find an explicit bijection of $A=\{x: a < x < b\}$ onto $B=\{y: 0<y<1 \}$

Can someone please help? I don't understand what is meant by 'explicit'. Would sinx, cosx or tanx classify?

Comment: Sorry! Is it visible now?

Comment: 'explicit' just means that you should write a concrete formula for the mappinmg function (and possibly its inverse) instead of e.g. merely showing the *existence* of such a bijection or describing a process that would provably result in such a bijection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

$$\begin{align*}g:(0,1)\to (a,b)&\;,\;\;g(x):=bx+(1-x)a=(b-a)x+a\\{}\\
f:(a,b)\to (0,1)&\;,\;\;f(x):=\frac{x-a}{b-a}\end{align*}$$

What's the relation between the functions $\;f,g\;$ ?